# C++ - basic thread question

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

*I have a simple threading question - how should the following be synchronized?*

I have main thread and a secondary thread that does something only once and something - more that once.

*Basically:*

***Secondary thread:***

```
{
   Do_Something_Once();

   while (not_important_condition) {
      Do_Something_Inside_Loop();
   }
}
```

I want to suspend my main thread unless `Do_Something_Once` action is done and right now I use a plain bool value `is_something_once_done = false;` to indicate if the action is finished.

Hence, the code of my ***main thread*** looks like this:

```
{
   Launch_Secondary_Thread();

   while (!is_something_once_done) {
      boost::this_thread::sleep(milliseconds(25));
   }
}
```

which obviously isn't the best way to perform such kind of synchronization.

***Any alternatives (better if `boost::thread` - powered)?***

Thank you

Comment: Note: There is no such thing as a basic thread question. There are 11 types of people: 1) People who think they can program using threads 10) People who know it is hard but think they understand threading 11) People who know it is hard and understand the interplay between threads is beyond them (These are the only people that are correct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for condition variables.

Check out the [Condition Variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) section of the boost docs - the example there is almost exactly what you're doing.

Whatever you do, don't do a busy-wait loop with sleep

Comment: "Whatever you do, don't do a busy-wait loop with sleep" - Care to elaborate why this is such bad thing?

Comment: @Stacked It's wasteful. On the one hand, it adds some unnecessary delay (average 12.5 ms in this example), on the other, it makes the system do unnecessary work (firing a timer N times). Choosing a sleep interval means making assumptions about the expected time for the task to finish & the acceptable tradeoffs between latency vs. CPU consumption. If things change (e.g., the code is now called in a loop 1000 times so the 12.5ms delay becomes 12.5 seconds) those assumptions may no longer be valid. Also, it's a "code smell" that suggests lack of awareness of available thread primitives.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [boost's condition variable mechanism](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar%5Fref).  It is designed for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Insert code that is appropriate for your platform where I have added comments below:

```
{
   // Create event visible by second thread to be signalled on completion
   Launch_Secondary_Thread();

   // Wait for event to be signalled
}

{
   Do_Something_Once();
   // set the event state to signalled so that 1st thread knows to continue working

   while (not_important_condition) {
      Do_Something_Inside_Loop();
   }
}
```

Make sure that the event DOES get signalled, even if 2nd thread exits abnormally after an exception or other error.  If not, your 1st thread will never wake up.  Unless you can put a timeout on the wait.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to go with mutex locks!

```
Do_Something_Once()
{
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock(mutex);
   // ...
}
```

Update:

For your particular case I would go with condition variable, as others suggested.

Comment: Updated with boost specific example.

Comment: Trying to undo down vote after edit is not working - adding +1 elsewhere in your history